# Can't login on site with python3

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, http-status-code-403

I have a problem when want to login at top500.org with Python3.4:
**urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: FORBIDDEN**, when Py3 try to execute 
   resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req) string in code below:

But I haven't any error when login in other sites!

```
import http.client
import http.cookiejar
import urllib.request

authentication_url = 'http://top_.org/accounts/login/'
payload = {
    'username': 'username',
    'password': '*******'
}

cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

opener.addheaders = [('User-agent',
    ('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10) '
    'AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
    'Chrome/13.0.782.13 Safari/535.1'))
]
opener.addheaders = [('Accept',   'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8')]
opener.addheaders = [('Accept-Language', 'en-EN')]
opener.addheaders = [('Referrer', authentication_url)]
opener.addheaders = [('Accept-Charset', 'UTF-8')]

urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload)
binary_data = data.encode('UTF-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(authentication_url, binary_data)

resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
contents = resp.read()
print(contents)
```

Comment: What is your question?  The code works and you got your answer: the site rejects your request.  You ultimately would have to ask the site why, but perhaps it does not like your password or User-agent.

Comment: Thank you very much. There is exist a token authentication on this webpage and I need to know token for authorization.